# Maintain certain number of running threads (JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to implement a piece of software that will make sure 10 `threads` running the same class all the time

All `threads` will terminate let's say after a certain number of seconds at random, but then, I want to make sure once they're terminated, they're replaced instantly by newly created `threads`.

Would you know if there's any library available?

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Comment: ... why?  What are you really attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Consider using threadpool (with size 10) executing your tasks. This way threads will be recycled instead of replaced (so this is not actualy answer for your question, but maybe for your need). Support for this is already in Java.

Comment: I'm trying to establish a service which continuously polls a database. Each returned row will be processed independetly by a thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather you use Thread Pool. Java `Executor` framework provides it.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Comment: Ok, but how should the code look like? I tried this code (http://pastebin.com/YXyepb7c), and only two threads are running, and then everything just goes in a loop:

Comment: you can start with Executor framework tutorial and check example- [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html), [link1](www.vogella.com/.../JavaConcurrency/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   ExecutorService  executorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);
```

public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)

```
Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed set of threads operating off a

shared unbounded queue. If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.

Parameters:
    nThreads - the number of threads in the pool 
Returns:
    the newly created thread pool
```